# The name "......." does not exist in the current context. error

Tags: c#

I am using a book to learn C# in which I was asked to type the following code but for `InFile` and `OutFile` used in the code it says:

> The name "InFile" does not exist in the current context. and The name
>   "OutFile" does not exist in the current context.

Code is given below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class NumberIt
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou need to include a filename.");
        }
        else
        {
            StreamReader InFile = null;
            StreamWriter OutFile = null;
        }
        try
        {
            InFile = File.OpenText(args[0]);
            OutFile = File.CreateText("OutFile.txt");
            Console.Write("\nNumbering...");
            string line = InFile.ReadLine();
            int ctr = 1;

        while (line != null)
        {
            OutFile.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", ctr.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0'), line);
            Console.Write("..{0}..", ctr.ToString());
            ctr++;
            line = InFile.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not find the file {0}", args[0]);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message); 
    }
    finally
    {
        if (InFile != null)
        {
            InFile.Close();
            OutFile.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("...Done");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't declared `InFile` or `OutFile` variables. Look carefully for a declaration in the book - otherwise, it may well be that the book is broken. (If it's really suggesting those variable names, I'm somewhat disconcerted already...)

Comment: No, @Jon, the variables are declared - just inside the else statement.

Comment: @MattiasÅslund: Eek - not sure how I didn't spot that. Ick ick ick.

Comment: Its pretty low quality code for a tutorial anyway... :/

Comment: You have misplaced a `}`. Compare carefully with the code in the book. The mismatch in indentation between `try` and `catch` is a giveaway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables are declared, but within a different scope. A 'scope' is -generally speaking- code within curly braces.

A declaration of variables is not a statement, so you cannot read your code like 'if the arguments are ok, then declare the two variables'. A variable declaration should be read like 'Here are two containers of type XY which will be known until the scope ends..'.

So your code should look similar to this.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length <= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou need to include a filename.");
    }
    else
    {
       StreamReader InFile = null;
       StreamWriter OutFile = null;

       try
       {
           InFile = File.OpenText(args[0]);
           OutFile = File.CreateText("OutFile.txt");
           Console.Write("\nNumbering...");
       ...
       }
       catch ... 
       {
       }
    // InFile and OutFile still known here !
    }
 // InFile and OutFile are unknown here !
```

Hope this describes what others already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you should declare InFile and Outfile in the scope of your Main method, or outside of the Main.

```
class NumberIt
{
    // declare them here
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    { 
       // or here
       ... 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables InFile and OutFile are out of scope for the try/catch block.

Move the `try/catch` block inside the else statement above it, so the variables are still available. Easiest is to  move the `}` above `try` to the very end.