# How to access a public void list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

this is my first time working with UWP and Xaml, and I am trying to create a memory matching game.

Here is what I have so far:

```
private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnStart.Opacity = 0;
        btnStart.IsEnabled = false;

        CardAssign();
    }

    public void CardAssign()
    {
        List<string> cards = new List<string>
        {
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardA.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardA.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardB.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardB.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardC.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardC.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardD.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardD.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardE.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardE.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardF.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardF.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardG.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardG.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardH.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardH.png"
        };

        var shuffledcards = cards.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();

        Card1Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[0]));
        Card2Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[1]));
        Card3Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[2]));
        Card4Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[3]));
        Card5Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[4]));
        Card6Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[5]));
        Card7Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[6]));
        Card8Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[7]));
        Card9Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[8]));
        Card10Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[9]));
        Card11Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[10]));
        Card12Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[11]));
        Card13Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[12]));
        Card14Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[13]));
        Card15Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[14]));
        Card16Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[15]));

        Countdown();
    }

    private async void Countdown()
    {
        await Task.Delay(7000);

        Hide();
    }

    private void Hide()
    {
        Card1.IsEnabled = true;
        Card2.IsEnabled = true;
        Card3.IsEnabled = true;
        Card4.IsEnabled = true;
        Card5.IsEnabled = true;
        Card6.IsEnabled = true;
        Card7.IsEnabled = true;
        Card8.IsEnabled = true;
        Card9.IsEnabled = true;
        Card10.IsEnabled = true;
        Card11.IsEnabled = true;
        Card12.IsEnabled = true;
        Card13.IsEnabled = true;
        Card14.IsEnabled = true;
        Card15.IsEnabled = true;
        Card16.IsEnabled = true;

        Card1Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card2Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card3Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card4Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card5Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card6Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card7Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card8Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card9Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card10Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card11Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card12Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card13Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card14Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card15Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card16Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
    }

    private void Card1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Card1Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledcards[0]));
    }
}
```

The only issue is that whenever I try to display the shuffled card image again, it says that it doesn't exist in the current context. I have not yet been able to figure out how to fix this! Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The error I'm getting is as follows:
Error   CS0103  The name 'shuffledcards' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Don't describe the error, instead paste it exactly as it appears. It sounds like a runtime error also called an Exception. Paste *all* the exception details. You can get them by calling `.ToString()` on the Exception instance. [edit] your question and add all the details.

Comment: It's a compilation error because `shuffledcards` is declared in `CardAssign` and OP is trying to use it in `Card1_Click`. The deleted answer was on the right track (as far as the first paragraph went, anyway) but referred to the wrong variable.

Comment: I added the exact error!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The name "......." does not exist in the current context. error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464536/the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-error)

Comment: I looked at that already and I still couldn't figure out, my brain is inept enough at this stuff yet haha

Comment: I've unhidden and updated my answer, answered a bit too quickly at first based on the title of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a "public void list", it's a variable that is defined within the scope of the method. To access it elsewhere simply set it as a field on the type.

I have moved the initialization of `shuffledCards` to the constructor because it is simply an ordered variant of a `List<string>` which contains fixed values.

Also, I have changed the return type of `Countdown` from `void` to `Task`. Any asynchronous methods should return a `Task` and not `void` ([unless it's an event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void))

```cs
public class MyType
{
    // Private field, accessible within the scope of this type
    private List<string> shuffledCards;

    // Constructor which is invoked when a new instance of this type is initialized
    public MyType()
    {
        List<string> cards = new List<string>
        {
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardA.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardA.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardB.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardB.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardC.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardC.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardD.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardD.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardE.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardE.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardF.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardF.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardG.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardG.png",
            "ms-appx:///Assets/CardH.png", "ms-appx:///Assets/CardH.png"
        };

        // Order cards and assign the result to shuffledCards
        shuffledCards = cards.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        btnStart.Opacity = 0;
        btnStart.IsEnabled = false;

        CardAssign();
    }

    public void CardAssign()
    {
        Card1Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[0]));
        Card2Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[1]));
        Card3Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[2]));
        Card4Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[3]));
        Card5Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[4]));
        Card6Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[5]));
        Card7Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[6]));
        Card8Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[7]));
        Card9Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[8]));
        Card10Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[9]));
        Card11Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[10]));
        Card12Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[11]));
        Card13Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[12]));
        Card14Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[13]));
        Card15Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[14]));
        Card16Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[15]));

        Countdown();
    }

    private async Task Countdown()
    {
        await Task.Delay(7000);

        Hide();
    }

    private void Hide()
    {
        Card1.IsEnabled = true;
        Card2.IsEnabled = true;
        Card3.IsEnabled = true;
        Card4.IsEnabled = true;
        Card5.IsEnabled = true;
        Card6.IsEnabled = true;
        Card7.IsEnabled = true;
        Card8.IsEnabled = true;
        Card9.IsEnabled = true;
        Card10.IsEnabled = true;
        Card11.IsEnabled = true;
        Card12.IsEnabled = true;
        Card13.IsEnabled = true;
        Card14.IsEnabled = true;
        Card15.IsEnabled = true;
        Card16.IsEnabled = true;

        Card1Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card2Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card3Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card4Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card5Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card6Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card7Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card8Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card9Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card10Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card11Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card12Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card13Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card14Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card15Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
        Card16Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Card Backs.png"));
    }

    private void Card1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Card1Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(shuffledCards[0]));
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried out your edits and I still get the 'shuffledcards' does not exist in the current context... I also get a new error with the public MyType() saying I need a return type

Comment: @Light C# is case sensitive, `shuffledCards` is the correct variable name. `MyType` also needs to match the name of your class, I have used `MyType` as your code example doesn't contain the full class code.

Comment: The `c` was lowercase in the original post.

Comment: My bad, you're totally right. I do still get the return type error though

Comment: Please read the final sentence in my previous message and see [the following link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

Comment: I see now!! Thank you very much for all your help my friends:)

Comment: Alright sorry to bother you both again, but now I get an exception on the first light of the CardAssign() method saying System.NullReferenceException
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Have you changed `public MyType` to match the name of your class, such as `public Form1` or `public MainForm`?

Comment: You've transitioned from compilation error to runtime error. That's progress. But without seeing what you have now (which might vary a bit from what was suggested), it would be difficult to assist you at this point. This would warrant a new question. *However*, I suggest reading this: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Questions about that exception usually gets closed with a reference to that answer, and very quickly.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the code to show you guys where I am at now! I appreciate all the help, thanks so much :) any ideas? If not I'll go back to the drawing board haha

Comment: Editing the answer like that is not the accepted process. The original problem was solved. This is a different problem. It warrants a new question.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I'm new to the site. Well, thank you anyways! :)

Comment: The reason why it's not the accepted process is because questions would be never ending which in turn makes it impossible for other developers to search for problems online and come across solutions.